# Apache.commons.cli Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

Want to use `Option`([apache.commons.cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/cli/Options.html)) as command and sub-command.

Ex.

1. myprogram job -dryrun
2. myprogram job -update
3. myprogram job -update -dryrun

What is best way to do this?

Tried with simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    test("job", "-update"); //works fine
    test("job", "-dryrun"); //works fine
    test("job", "-update", "-dryrun"); // doesn't work
}
public static void test(String... args) throws ParseException {
    GnuParser parser = new GnuParser();
    Options options = new Options();
    OptionGroup option = new OptionGroup();
    option.addOption(new Option("dryrun", "dryrun"));
    option.addOption(new Option("update", "update"));
    options.addOptionGroup(option);
    parser.parse(options, args);
}
```

Error:

```
test("job", "-update", "-dryrun");
fails with, Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.cli.AlreadySelectedException: The option 'dryrun' was specified but an option from this group has already been selected: 'update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using OptionGroup? You can use OptionBuilder See Commons CLI Usage Scenarios http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html For complete code with working project see https://github.com/firefoxNX/StackOverflow/tree/master/CommonsCli

```
        Options options = new Options();
        Option dryrunOption = OptionBuilder.withArgName("dryrun")
                .withDescription("dry run").create("dryrun");
        options.addOption(dryrunOption);

        Option updateOption = OptionBuilder.withArgName("update")
                .withDescription("update").create("update");
        options.addOption(updateOption);

        // create the parser
        GnuParser parser = new GnuParser();
            // parse the command line arguments
            CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args);
            Option[] opts = line.getOptions();
            for(String arg: line.getArgs()){
                System.out.println(arg);
            }
            for(Option opt: opts){
                System.out.println(opt.getOpt()+" : "+opt.getValue());
            }
```